# How to get jenkins job build status using java

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-cli

I'm trying to write a java program which will provide the build status of a particular job, this Jenkins job is running at every hour and I want to get the build status(success or failed) of each build for the last 24 hours. I can get the build information from the below url format : /job//api/json?tree=allBuilds[result,number,url,timestamp] OR
http://jenkins.myteam-aws.local:8080/job/HealthCheckerApp/api/json?tree=allBuilds[result,number,url,timestamp]
But the problem is when I logged in to the application I can retrieve the information but when I call the above url from the java application then I am getting the 500 error, possible cause of this error could be login credentials are missing.
So how could I read this json data from the URL?
Seeking your help in this regard.

```
// below code will read the json data from the given url

public class JsonReader {

private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
        sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        String jsonText = readAll(rd);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
        return json;
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
    System.out.println("inside main-------->");
    JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://jenkins.myteam-aws.local:8080/job/HealthCheckerApp/api/json?tree=allBuilds[result,number,url,timestamp]");

    System.out.println("Json object created: " + json);
    System.out.println(json.toString());
}
}
```

Result: SUCCESS

Built No: 4715

url: http://jenkins.myteam-aws.local:8080/job/Thor-API-Prod-Health-Checker/4715/

Timestamp: 1545803471449

Comment: Do you have access to the Jenkins log? Maybe you can figure it out what is the real 500 error if it's because of the login or what...

Comment: I did not check the logs, when I execute the program then in Netbeans it showing me the 500 error, when I login via a selenium to jenkins and call the url then I am not getting such error.

Comment: driver.get("http://jenkins.myteam-aws.local:8080");
WebElement userTextField = driver.findElement(By.id("j_username"));
userTextField.sendKeys(user);
WebElement PassTextField = driver.findElement(By.name("j_password"));
PassTextField.sendKeys(pass);
driver.findElement(By.id("yui-gen1-button")).click();
driver.get("http://jenkins.myteam-aws.local:8080/job/HealthCheckerApp/api/json?tree=allBuilds[result,number,url,timestamp]");

Comment: Is the java client safe? I mean is it a trusted application?

Comment: @JRichardsz Sorry I did not understand the meaning of trusted here, can you pls explain me.

Comment: I mean, is your java client inside your LAN? Because your current code could be work using some jenkins credentials user/pasword. If this java application would be outside your network, using credentials it would not be a solution. Are you able to use jenkins credentials in your java code to get the build status?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to Jenkins log and still think is a login problem, try with an **username** and an **API Token**.

You can get the API Token from `http://<jenkins-server>/user/<username>/configure`

And here you have two different ways to call with user and token to Jenkins. For example, a list of all jobs:

`curl -X GET http://<jenkins-server>/api/json?pretty=true --user <username>:<api-token>`

or an example for deleting a job

`http://<username>:<api-token>@<jenkins-server>/job/<job-name>/doDelete`

Comment: Do we have some other method than doDelete, checking in production, can't perform these operations :(

Comment: Maybe is a permission problem. Are you the Jenkins admin or have the proper permissions? Here you have mor examples https://gist.github.com/marshyski/abaa1ccbcee5b15db92c

Answer (score 0):

If you call URL.openConnection first and cast to HttpURLConnection then you can check the status and read the error text using getErrorStream() and throw an exception containing the error message.

Just replace the code for this method:

```
public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        // error occurred, get details and throw exception
        // this uses Commons IO to read all bytes from an InputStream
        byte[] errorBytes = IOUtils.readFully(conn.getErrorStream(), 2048, false);
        // if you have Java 9+ then use this instead:
        // byte[] errorBytes = conn.getErrorStream().readFully();
        String msg = new String(errorBytes, "UTF-8");
        throw new IOException(msg);
    }
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    try {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        String jsonText = readAll(rd);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
        return json;
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head resURL="/static/da057b0c" data-rooturl="" data-resurl="/static/da057b0c">
    <title>Jenkins [Jenkins]</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/da057b0c/css/layout-common.css" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/da057b0c/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/da057b0c/css/color.css" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/da057b0c/css/responsive-grid.css" type="text/css" />
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/da057b0c/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />

Comment: <link color="black" rel="mask-icon" href="/images/mask-icon.svg" />
 <script>var isRunAsTest=false; var rootURL=""; var resURL="/static/da057b0c";</script>
 <script src="/static/da057b0c/scripts/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/static/da057b0c/scripts/behavior.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src='/adjuncts/da057b0c/org/kohsuke/stapler/bind.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
 <script src="/static/da057b0c/scripts/yui/yahoo/yahoo-min.js"></script>
 <script src="/static/da057b0c/scripts/yui/dom/dom-min.js"></script>

Comment: <script src="/static/da057b0c/scripts/yui/event/event-min.js"></script>
 <script src="/static/da057b0c/scripts/yui/animation/animation-min.js">
 </script><script src="/static/da057b0c/scripts/yui/dragdrop/dragdrop-min.js"></script>
 <script src="/static/da057b0c/scripts/yui/container/container-min.js"></script>
 <script src="/static/da057b0c/scripts/yui/connection/connection-min.js"></script>
 <script src="/static/da057b0c/scripts/yui/datasource/datasource-min.js"></script>

Comment: <script src="/static/da057b0c/scripts/yui/autocomplete/autocomplete-min.js"></script>
 <script src="/static/da057b0c/scripts/yui/menu/menu-min.js"></script>
 <script src="/static/da057b0c/scripts/yui/element/element-min.js"></script>
 <script src="/static/da057b0c/scripts/yui/button/button-min.js"></script>
 <script src="/static/da057b0c/scripts/yui/storage/storage-min.js"></script>
 <script src="/static/da057b0c/scripts/hudson-behavior.js" type="text/
 at automation.JsonReader.readJsonFromUrl(JsonReader.java:51)

Comment: It is cutting off the text before it gets to the actual error message. Increase the 2048 to 4096 and see if it shows up.

Comment: Some description in the bottom lines: <div id="error-description"><p>A problem occurred while processing the request.Please check <a href="https://jenkins.io/redirect/issue-tracker">our bug tracker</a> to see if a similar problem has already been reported.
        If it is already reported, please vote and put a comment on it to let us gauge the impact of the problem.
        If you think this is a new issue, please file a new issue.
        When you file an issue, make sure to add the entire stack trace, along with the version of Jenkins and relevant plugins.

Comment: <a href="https://jenkins.io/redirect/users-mailing-list">The users list</a> might be also useful in understanding what has happened.</p><h2>Stack trace</h2><pre style="margin:2em; clear:both">java.lang.NullPointerException
</pre></div></div></div>

Comment: in the bootom lines you can see the "java.lang.NullPointerException", most probably when I am trying to access the URL then it is checking the user credentials,when it does not found any thing then it is throwing the exception.

Comment: If you see a line number you can search for the code and see what is causing the null pointer exception. Otherwise I would suggest using curl like @dcalap suggested to figure out the right URL and headers to send, then write the java code.